# Graphics card compatibility on older hardware

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, motherboard

I have a desktop with a [Gigabyte Motherboard (GA-Z77X-UD5H)](https://www.gigabyte.com/pk/Motherboard/GA-Z77X-UD5H-rev-10/sp#sp) with an [Intel Core i7-3770K Processor](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/65523/intel-core-i7-3770k-processor-8m-cache-up-to-3-90-ghz.html) and an [NVIDIA GeForce GTX 680](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/graphics-cards/geforce-gtx-680/specifications/) graphics card.

I am now looking to upgrade to an [NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060](https://www.nvidia.com/en-in/geforce/products/10series/geforce-gtx-1060/#specs) and am not sure if the hardware is compatible.

According to the specs, both seem to support PCIe 3.0 but I wanted to make sure it will work together and if it is worth the upgrade rather than waiting and building a new PC.

**UPDATE:**

This question was primarily about compatibility but I did ask a subjective question so here some context.

I use this primarily as a very capable dev machine and also have a huge Steam library of modern games, a lot of them released this year. This rig runs all of them on medium settings without issue, but being so old, the 680 has started to crash on occasion.

The 1060 is very capable and very cheap at around $200 in my region. I'd rather upgrade now and wait to build the $2.5k+ rig next year. Thank you for all your comments.

Comment: This machine has 32GB of RAM, 2TB of SSDs, and runs most modern games just fine on medium settings. Granted the motherboard is old, but I'd rather upgrade now and save up to get a fully loaded new machine in a yer.

Comment: @tetsujin I'm not a gamer, and I know you know your stuff - but what you say surprises me. I know the CPU in question to be quite capable despite its age, and certainly not a "lada" - I know there is a bit more to it -memory speeds? But is it really that much of a bottleneck that a new GPU won't provide a massive improvement over a ?7 year? old one?

Comment: Also, presumably you can take the GTX1060 and add it to a new rig later?

Comment: @tetsujin - sorry to push it - but Xeon workloads are hardly comparable to gaming ones. As I understand it Gaming does most of the heavy lifting in the GPU.

Comment: Yes it's compatible, and the CPU is more than capable of keeping up with a 1060. You will get FPS increases, and be able to play games on at least high settings, probably some mixed custom settings of high/ultra would work too on certain games. If you can afford to save up for a higher end GPU I would. If you don't care too much about graphics overall, you will see FPS improvement at higher graphics settings from the 680 to the 1060.

Comment: Found https://pc-builds.com/calculator/Core_i7-3770/GeForce_GTX_1060/0es0Ve/ - which I think will help quantify the gains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website PVPartPicker lists the following in
[GA-Z77X-UD5H ATX LGA1155 Compatible Video Cards](https://pcpartpicker.com/products/video-card/?compatible_with=6WphP6):

- MSI GeForce GTX 1060 6GT OCV1
- MSI GeForce GTX 1060 3G OCV1
- MSI GEFORCE GTX 1060 6GT OC
- MSI GeForce GTX 1060 6GT V1

So I believe that there wouldn't be any compatibility problem.

Looking at the power requirements,
the GTX 680 is rated at maximum 195 W, while the the GTX 1060 is surprisingly
rated at 120 W, so no problem there either.

It seems like it should work without a hitch.